# Get all the site collections where Sharepoint app is instalation

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, apps-development, pnp

In need of an approach how a user can identify whether an app is installed on the site collection or not. App can be a provider hosted or sharepoint hosted but site collection will be on office 365. Do we have any relavent functions if i use PnP sharepoint core components.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I got how to get the installed app but if the app is added to the sites using app stamping, unable to get the information. Any approach to get site collections when  apps deployed to site using app stamping will be appriciated.

Comment: did u try with AppInstalled eventreceiver?
https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EventReceivers
?